# How do I add a method to a Rails app which updates a collection of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, rails-activerecord

I have a very standard CRUD app in Rails & Jquery Mobile with two models relevant to my question:

```
class Wall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :problems
end

class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  # boolean attribute is_live
  belongs_to  :wall
end
```

When showing each Wall, I'm grabbing each Problem belonging to that wall for which is_live == true.  My goal now is to create a method for 'clearing' a wall of all problems by finding each problem on a wall with is_live == true and updating is_live to be false.

I do not, however, know the best practice/approach to find and update each of the appropriate objects.  (This will be a restricted function only available to those with 'admin' privileges.)  Should I:

1. Add a link_to that posts to a newly created WallController action
   like below?

   ```
   def clear_wall
     @wall = Wall.find(params[:id])
     @problems = @wall.problems.where(:is_live => true)
     @problem.each {|p| p.update_attribute(:is_live => false) }

     redirect_to(walls_url)
   end
   ```
2. Add a form_for that submits to execute the same controller code?
3. Add a new method to the Wall model to handle this?

I'm probably overthinking this pretty heavily, but I'd appreciate some direction before I stumble down an overly-complicated road that causes problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't need to pass any data to the server other than the ID which will be in the URL, so using a `link_to` should be fine.

Make this method POST using `:method => :post` as you are changing data on the server - changing data without POSTing is a bad idea

If you don't need a special view, you can also use `:remote => true` to use AJAX to submit a form to this URL. Otherwise, the `redirect_to` in your question will suffice.

See the [ActionView](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) docs for more info about how to construct your `link_to`

I would then Implement the logic (as below) in your controller directly

**Using `update_all` to update many objects in the DB**

ActiveRecord has an `update_all` method you can call on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

It doesn't [load the models from the DB, or call callbacks](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) but since setting anything that is not false to false is functionally equivalent to setting everything to false using it like this might suit your purpose.

`Wall.find(params[:id]).problems.update_all(:is_live => false)`

You can supply a conditional parameter to `update_all`

`Wall.find(params[:id]).problems.update_all(:is_live => false, "is_live = true")`

or alternatively perform a where first, but this will load all of the data from the DB first and in your case seems unnecessary. The important thing to note here, is that the `update_all` method works on `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not `ActiveRecord::Base`

`Wall.find(params[:id]).problems.where(:is_live => true).update_all(:is_live => false)`

Comment: Emma, pointing me towards update_all is super useful and does look like a cleaner way to perform the update, but I'm actually just as uncertain about how to construct the view to handle this.  link_to versus form_for, whether it should be a POST or a PUT, etc.

Comment: @IanWhalen I've updated my answer (a few times!) so hopefully it makes a little more sense to your actual question now.

Comment: Something like `link_to "Clear Wall", clear_wall_url(@wall.id), :method => :post`

Comment: For future readers of this question, worth noting that I also had to update routes.rb with a new route as discussed at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions